# node-orm2 - Association functions are not created

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-orm2

When I create an many-to-one relationship with `hasOne()` function, I only get available the function `findBy`, but none of the setters and getters that should be available are created.

For example:

I have a `User` model and a `UserType` model

```
var UserType = db.define('user_types',{
    type_name: String
});

var User = db.define('users', {
    name: String,
    last_name: String
}).hasOne('type', UserType);
```

After this, my Users model only have a `findByType()` function thats works great but I don't have a `setType()` or `getType()` function.

Maybe I'm missing something!

Comment: Have you found any solution...?? I'm facing the same problem...